# Accessing $scope variables inside a nested function call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS app using Underscore.js for some filtering. I have created a custom directive that is bound to update the members of an array which belongs to $scope. After the adjustment of a filter is applied it calls a $scope function to apply the filters to the results. My problem now is that accessing the $scope object from inside the Underscore `filter` function does not observe the binding updates. Here is the directive:

```
app.directive('range', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            top: "=top",
            bottom: "=bottom",
            isDisabled: "=disable",
            attid: "=attid",
            whenchanged: "&"
        },
        link: function(scope,elem,attrs) {
            jQuery(elem).each(function () {
                var el = jQuery(this);
                jQuery.ui.slider.prototype.widgetEventPrefix = 'slider';
                el.slider({
                    range: true,
                    disabled: scope.isDisabled,
                    min: scope.bottom,
                    max: scope.top,
                    values: [scope.bottom, scope.top],
                    orientation: "vertical",
                    slide: function (event, ui) {
                        jQuery("#" + scope.attid + "_label_top").val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
                        jQuery("#" + scope.attid + "_label_bottom").val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
                        scope.top = ui.values[ 1 ];
                        scope.bottom = ui.values[ 0 ];
                    },
                    stop: function (event, ui) {
                        scope.whenchanged();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

and here is the HTML using the directive:

```
<div range class="mps-slider" id="{{attribute.id}}" bottom="$parent.mpsfilters[attribute.id].range_bottom" top="$parent.mpsfilters[attribute.id].range_top" disable="$parent.mpsfilters[attribute.id].sliderDisabled" attid="attribute.id" ng-model="$parent.mpsfilters[attribute.id]" whenchanged="$parent.narrow()"></div>
```

*note: you are seeing $parent here because this is inside a directive*

and here is the scope function in the controller:

```
$scope.narrow = function () {
    console.log($scope.mpsfilters); // this line logs the values from my adjustments to the filter
    var filtered = _.filter(controller.parts, function (obj) {
        var result;
        for (var key in $scope.mpsfilters) {
            if ($scope.mpsfilters.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var keyname = key + '_search_value';
                var paKey = controller.findKey(obj.paValues, keyname);
                var paValue = obj.paValues[paKey][keyname];
                console.log($scope.mpsfilters[key]); // this logs the original values, not reflecting the adjustment
                result = (paValue >= $scope.mpsfilters[key].range_bottom && paValue <= $scope.mpsfilters[key].range_top);
            }
        }
        return result;
    });
    controller.parts = filtered;
    controller.filteredCount = filtered.length;
    $scope.$apply();
};
```

See the comments in the code snippet for context. Logging the array outside of the Underscore filter call reflects the data-binding, but not from inside. I can't figure out how to pass the $scope variable into that function because it is pre-defined by Underscore.

Comment: From what I see you don't assign values to `$scope.mpsfilters[key]` nowhere.

Comment: Values are assigned to `$scope.mpsfilters` in the directive. That part is working because when I log to the console (line 2 in the code example above) I can see the value reflect what I did to the filtering control. The console.log on line 10 shows the original default value.

Comment: What kind of scope you have in that directive, are you sure it's the same scope?

Comment: Edited the question to include more reference code.

Comment: a plunker would be awesome.

Comment: Let me see what I can do. This is part of a highly-integrated app, but I'll try to strip out enough to get something to play with.

Comment: You say you are using $parent because the html is inside a directive.  So you have nested directives?  And you are trying to get at the scope of a directive inside a directive from the controller?  Is that right?

Comment: @tpie yes. The product category can have a variable amount of attributes, so I made a directive to add them dynamically. Inside that directive it displays some static info as well as the range slider. I turned the range slider into another directive so I could add Angular binding to it. It *appears* to work well because I can see it update the scope in line 2 of the controller code above.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are getting the data out of the directive, tinkering with it, and trying to push it back down, right?
I think the usual story is, you can only get one way binding or it works one time and then quits...

Comment: @tpie that is not the issue. If I manipulate the data manually and then do $scope.apply it works great. My issue here is having access to the updated $scope from *inside* the callback function I'm passing into Underscore's `.filter()` function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75848/discussion-between-tpie-and-claywhipkey).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working code after @tpie being very helpful in chat. The issue was scope-related. Because the range slider directive was being used in another directive, the scope variable change was not bubbling up to the parent. Here's a visual representation using aliases:

```
main application template (parent)
- attribute header directive (child)
- - range slider directive (grandchild)
```

Final code:

**HTML for the range slider as seen in the (child) directive template**

```
<div range class="mps-slider" id="{{attribute.id}}" bottom="$parent.mpsfilters[attribute.id].range_bottom" top="$parent.mpsfilters[attribute.id].range_top" disable="$parent.mpsfilters[attribute.id].sliderDisabled" attid="attribute.id" ng-model="$parent.mpsfilters[attribute.id]" mpsfilters="$parent.mpsfilters" whenchanged="$parent.narrow()"></div>
```

I added `mpsfilters="$parent.mpsfilters"` as an attribute on the div.

**Directive code for the range slider (grandchild)**

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('range', [function () {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                scope: {
                    top: "=top",
                    bottom: "=bottom",
                    isDisabled: "=disable",
                    attid: "=attid",
                    mpsfilters: "=mpsfilters",
                    whenchanged: "&"
                },
                link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
                    jQuery(elem).each(function () {
                        var el = jQuery(this);
                        jQuery.ui.slider.prototype.widgetEventPrefix = 'slider';
                        el.slider({
                            range: true,
                            disabled: scope.isDisabled,
                            min: scope.bottom,
                            max: scope.top,
                            values: [scope.bottom, scope.top],
                            orientation: "vertical",
                            slide: function (event, ui) {
                                jQuery("#" + scope.attid + "_label_top").val(ui.values[ 1 ]);
                                jQuery("#" + scope.attid + "_label_bottom").val(ui.values[ 0 ]);
                                scope.top = ui.values[ 1 ];
                                scope.mpsfilters[scope.attid].range_top = ui.values[ 1 ];
                                scope.bottom = ui.values[ 0 ];
                                scope.mpsfilters[scope.attid].range_bottom = ui.values[ 0 ];
                            },
                            stop: function (event, ui) {
                                scope.whenchanged();
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            };
        }]);
```

Two changes here. I added the local scope property "mpsfilters" with binding to the directive attribute. In combination with the addition above, this new scope property is now directly bound to the parent scope for mpsfilters. The second change is that I am updating the filter value inside the `slide` property of the slider constructor.

This was all I needed to change as I could now use the updated filter values inside the controller function without problems.